# How to do full screen activity?

Tags: android

How to do layout for activity without button's back, home, watch bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess this is not possible. Android has to provide a way to the user to get back to home screen or exit an application. Hence, an application cannot get to remove them completely.